# Disabling password authentication

Tags: linux, ssh, authentication, password

Suppose I want to allow SSH authentication only, and disable password authentication.

In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` I've typically done this:

```ini
PasswordAuthentication no
```

But in some answers people recommend this:

```ini
PasswordAuthentication no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
UsePAM no
```

How do those differ? What is the correct way to disable password auth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PasswordAuthentication` performs strictly "username,password" chat, it's a special case of a more generic `KbdInteractiveAuthentication` (for which `ChallengeResponseAuthentication` is a deprecated alias), which can provide arbitrary chat, *including* "username,password". If you want to disable any kind of chat-based authentication, you need to disable both.

`UsePAM` is needed to provide system pluggable authentication module support for both of these (and if enabled, it requires running sshd strictly as root). It is disabled by default.

Comment: So that I am sure I understand you, in my use case of "allow ssh auth and not allow password auth", I should do this: `PasswordAuthentication no` and `ChallengeResponseAuthentication no`.

Comment: BTW my debian latest (v11) `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` has no `KbdInteractiveAuthentication`.

Comment: Read `man sshd_config`. Always read `man`. I have OpenSSH 9.3 here, Debian might have older version where it wasn't deprecated yet.